# Certificate public key accessing at x64 configuration

Tags: c++, windows, ssl-certificate, cryptoapi

I am trying to access a public key of a certificate from the Certificate Store, using Windows CryptoAPI. It works at x86 project configuration, but fails at x64 configuration as the struct that it fills is empty. I cannot change the project's configuration, because then I have to change a whole lot of things.
Does anybody know of a way to do it in x64 bit configuration ?

Here is what I have at x86:

```
HCERTSTORE CertStore = CertOpenStore( CERT_STORE_PROV_SYSTEM, 0, NULL, CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_CURRENT_USER, L"My" );

PCCERT_CONTEXT CertContext = CertFindCertificateInStore( CertStore, X509_ASN_ENCODING|PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING, 0, CERT_FIND_SUBJECT_STR_A, CertName, NULL );

CryptDecodeObjectEx((PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING | X509_ASN_ENCODING), 
    CNG_RSA_PUBLIC_KEY_BLOB, 
    CertContext->pCertInfo->SubjectPublicKeyInfo.PublicKey.pbData, // The pbData member is filled correctly
    CertContext->pCertInfo->SubjectPublicKeyInfo.PublicKey.cbData, // The cbData member is filled with the correct length of the public key
    CRYPT_ENCODE_ALLOC_FLAG, 
    NULL, 
    &DecodedPublicKey, 
    &DecodedPublicLength); // Executes with success, returns the public key, which I am sure is correct, because I tested it.
```

And for x64 I have the exact same thing, but the pbData and cbData members are not filled from the `CertFindCertificateInStore`:

```
HCERTSTORE CertStore = CertOpenStore( CERT_STORE_PROV_SYSTEM, 0, NULL, CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_CURRENT_USER, L"My" );

PCCERT_CONTEXT CertContext = CertFindCertificateInStore( CertStore, X509_ASN_ENCODING|PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING, 0, CERT_FIND_SUBJECT_STR_A, CertName, NULL );

CryptDecodeObjectEx((PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING | X509_ASN_ENCODING), 
    CNG_RSA_PUBLIC_KEY_BLOB, 
    CertContext->pCertInfo->SubjectPublicKeyInfo.PublicKey.pbData, // pbData member is null
    CertContext->pCertInfo->SubjectPublicKeyInfo.PublicKey.cbData, // cbData member is 0
    CRYPT_ENCODE_ALLOC_FLAG, 
    NULL, 
    &DecodedPublicKey, 
    &DecodedPublicLength);
```

In fact, every member of the `CertContext` is empty, but the `CertFindCertificateInStore` did not return null, which is really strange. Seems like a bug to me...

Comment: Out of curiosity, I [googled "Windows CryptoAPI Certificate public key accessing at x64 configuration"](https://www.google.com/search?q=Windows+CryptoAPI+Certificate+public+key+accessing+at+x64+configuration). Maybe, you find something useful. (1st hit was your question itself.) ;-)

Comment: However, I found this on [secureblackbox.com](https://www.secureblackbox.com/kb/help/ref_howto_pki_certstg_usewcs.html) which might be useful: _Sometimes access to a hardware private key via TElWinCertStorage results in a failure. Usually this happens when the hardware CSP vendor does not provide a 64-bit version of the driver. This problem is resolvable by explicitly targeting the user's application the x86/x64 platform._

Comment: no any different 32 or 64 bit code you use. result will be the same, if no errors in code. *In fact, every member of the CertContext is empty, but the CertFindCertificateInStore did not return null* - can not be. or you paste not full working code or bad look or some hooks in your process

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. It was the structures alignment. Apparently the 32bit version of the wincrypt library uses the same alignment as my configuration, but the 64bit one uses different alignment. Adjusting the alignment of the structures fixed it.